# Converting html template with jquery to React js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a html template like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
</body>
some body
<script type="text/javascript">
**Some JQUERY**
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to convert it into react functional component.Everything is done But in the script tag there is some JQUERY written for one of the elements in the body.

Can anyone tell me how to implement this jquery in my component or any way to convert the functions in script tag into javascript functions??

Comment: Stop and think about what you are asking....how to convert code we can't see or have any idea what it does into something else. Sounds like magic

Comment: Sorry i cant put the code here.Basically my question is how can i implement jquery code in react functional component

Comment: Well that depends on what the specific code does which you have given absolutely no detail. jQuery can be used to do many many things and there is no *one size fits all* answer to question without specifics

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using react functional component or by using react hooks.

**Example:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"; 

import * as $ from "jquery";

const HtmlToReact = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded} =useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) {
      setLoaded(true);
      // ... jquery//;    
     }
   },[loaded]);
  return (
    <body>
      //statement
    </body>
  )
}
```